# How does mysql work with two equal indices?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Mysql does not prevent the creation of an index for the same column(s) when different index names are used. I guess that internally only one index is created and updated, but I better ask here if this is true.

When my suggestion is not right, what is the reason to maintain the index more than one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also the case when a table has two indexes, one for `field-1` and a compound one for `(field-1, field-2)`. The second index makes the first unneeded but I doubt that MySQL does anything less than maintaining both indexes.

It's the developer's or DBA's job to figure than an index is duplicate or redundant and should be removed.

My guess for the reason that such duplicates appeared in the first place is that someone made tests in the past with indexes to optimize some queries and forgot to remove them when done.

Answer (score 3):

There should be only one index maintained as @Tomalak mentioned. Check this links once

[How do MySQL indexes work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567981/how-do-mysql-indexes-work)

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/17/duplicate-indexes-and-redundant-indexes/

ADD:

There could be cases of having redundent indexes on a column. You can find them out by using the SP

```
I_S_REDUNDANT_INDEXES: lists all redundant indexes
```

To remove them

```
I_S_REDUNDANT_INDEXES_DROP
```

See this link

http://malcook-gedanken.blogspot.com/2008_10_01_archive.html

Comment: SP = Stored Procedure. Those are the stored procedure to find/list out redundant indexex and remove them if you want to. To be employed against the database. Check this link http://malcook-gedanken.blogspot.com/2008_10_01_archive.html

Comment: Right, so these are stored procedures that must be looked up in the "Community Feedback section" and created in your database. This might be worth mentioning in your answer...?

Comment: @Tomalak, I did mentioned them in my answer. Do you want me to add this link to my answer as well? Will do that then.

Comment: I think it would be useful, yes. You are referring to specific procedures that a third-party has written.

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, I'd hope that only one of the two indexes is actually maintained internally. But it doesn't matter, because you shouldn't be doing this.
- There is no reason to maintain two duplicate indexes.

Comment: Found this in a schema of another project, where I'm not a developer. In the question I mean that mysql not the programmer maintains the index.

Comment: @giftnuss: Yes, and I used the same meaning of 'maintain'. I think that you should ask the developer why (s)he did this, because it's silly and without purpose (though, ultimately, harmless).

Answer (score 2):

MySQL allows you to create redundant indexes and it maintains them all.

Try [mk-duplicate-key-checker](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-duplicate-key-checker.html) which is a nice tool that finds duplicate/redundant indexes.  The output has ALTER TABLE statements to drop the duplicates, so you can run it as an SQL script.  But I recommend reviewing the output before executing it.