# How many comparisons will binary search make in the worst case using this algorithm?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory, binary-search

Hi there below is the pseudo code for my binary search implementation:

```
Input: (A[0...n-1], K)
begin
   l ← 0; r ← n-1
   while l ≤ r do
      m ← floor((l+r)/2)
      if K > A[m] then l ← m+1
      else if K < A[m] then r ← m-1 else return m
      end if 
   end while
   return -1 // key not found
end
```

I was just wondering how to calculate the number of comparisons this implementation would make in the worst case for a sorted array of size n?

Would the number of comparisons = lg n + 1? or something different?

Comment: There’s an error in your code: `if K > A[m] then return l ← m+1` should be `if K > A[m] then l ← m+1` without the `return`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The worst-case in this case is, if the element K is not present in A and smaller than all elements in A. Then we have two comparisons in each step: `K > A[m]` and `K < A[m]`.

For in each step the array is being cut into two parts, each of the size `(n-1)/2`, we have a maximum of `log_2(n-1)` steps.

This leads to a total of `2*log_2(n-1)` comparisons, which asymptotically indeed equals to `O(log(n))`.

Comment: The worst case should be if all elements are the same! Thus the time complexity should be O(n)

Answer (score 12):

A very minor correction to [hielsnoppe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571300/1011995):

In an `n`-element array (`n > 0`), the element to compare is at index `m = floor((n-1)/2)`. So there are three possibilities

1. `A[m] < K`, then after one comparison, the search continues in an `n-1-m = ceiling((n-1)/2)`-element array.
2. `A[m] > K`, then after two comparisons, the search continues in an `m`-element array.
3. `A[m] == K`, then we're done after two comparisons.

So if we denote the maximal (worst-case) number of comparisons for a search in an `n`-element array by `C(n)`, we have

```
C(0) = 0
C(n) = max { 1 + C(ceiling((n-1)/2), 2 + C(floor((n-1)/2) }, n > 0
```

For odd `n = 2k+1`, the floor and ceiling are identical, so the maximum is evidently the latter,

```
C(2k+1) = 2 + C(k)
```

and for even `n = 2k`, we find

```
C(2k) = max { 1 + C(k), 2 + C(k-1) }.
```

For `n = 2`, that resolves to `C(2) = 1 + C(1) = 1 + 2 = 3`, for all larger even `n`, the maximum is `2 + C(k-1)`, since for `n >= 1` we have `C(n) <= C(n+1) <= C(n) + 1`.

Evaluating the recursion for the first few `n`, we find

```
C(0) = 0
C(1) = 2
C(2) = 3
C(3) = C(4) = 4
C(5) = C(6) = 5
C(7) = C(8) = C(9) = C(10) = 6
C(11) = ... = C(14) = 7
C(15) = ... = C(22) = 8
C(23) = ... = C(30) = 9
```

So by induction we prove

```
C(n) = 2k, if 2^k <= n+1 < 2k + 2^(k-1), and
C(n) = 2k+1, if 2^k + 2^(k-1) <= n+1 < 2^(k+1)
```

or

```
C(n) = 2*log2(n+1) + floor(2*(n+1)/(3*2^floor(log2(n+1)))).
```

This is an exact upper bound.

Comment: Can I say that for N sorted elements, there will be floor(log2(N+1)) comparisons in the worst case. By the worst case, I mean that the element is not in the list?

Answer (score 6):

According to the wikipedia page on [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), the worst-case performance of this algorithm is `O(lg n)`, which measures the asymptotical number of comparisons needed. The *actual* worst-case number of comparisons would be `2*lg(n-1)`, as has been pointed in @hielsnoppe's answer.

The pseudocode in the question represents the typical implementation of a binary search, so the expected performance complexities hold for an array (or vector) of size `n`:

- Best case performance:    `O(1)`
- Average case performance: `O(lg n)`
- Worst case performance:   `O(lg n)`

On closer inspection, there are two problems with the pseudocode in the question:

- The line: `if K > A[m] then return l ← m+1` should read `if K > A[m] then l ← m+1`. You can't return yet
- The line: `m ← floor((l+r)/2)` might cause an overflow if the numbers are large enough when working with fixed-size integers. The correct syntax varies depending on the actual programming language you're using, but something along this will fix the problem: `m ← (l + r) >>> 1`, where `>>>` is the unsigned right shift operator. Read more about the problem in [here](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html).