# Binary Search: Number of comparisons in the worst case

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, binary-search

I am trying to figure out the number of comparisons that binary search does on an array of a given size *in the worst case*.

Let's say there is an array A with 123,456 elements (or any other number). Binary search is applied to find some element E. The comparison is to determine whether A[i] = E. How many times would this comparison be executed in the worst case?

According to [this](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-determine-the-number-of-comparisons-in-Binary-Search) post, the number of worst case comparisons is 2logn+1.
Result: 50

According to [this](http://watson.latech.edu/book/algorithms/algorithmsSearching2.html) post, the max. number of binary search comparisons is log2(n+1).
Result: 25

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571170/how-many-comparisons-will-binary-search-make-in-the-worst-case-using-this-algori) post, the number of comparisons is 2logn-1.
Result: 50

I am confused by the different answers. Can anyone tell me which one is correct and how I can determine the maximum number of comparisons in the worst case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Performance) Wiki page:

> In the worst case, binary search makes `floor(log2(n)+1)` iterations of the comparison loop, where the `floor` notation denotes the floor function that yields the greatest integer less than or equal to the argument, and `log2` is the binary logarithm. This is because the worst case is reached when the search reaches the deepest level of the tree, and there are always `floor(log2(n)+1)` levels in the tree for any binary search.

Also, it's not enough to consider only comparisons `A[i] = E`. The binary search also includes comparisons `E <= A[mid]`, where the `mid` is the midpoint of the index interval.