# MySQL query optimization for large single table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, query-optimization

I need to ask you about making my MySQL query more efficient. I have a table of posts with 1M records.

I am not using any join, and it's fetching result from database in 5-10 seconds - I don't know how can I make it efficient to retrieve data fast. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    post_id, post_title, post_des, post_date,
    post_status, user_id, post_price
FROM
    post
```

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `post_des` text NOT NULL,
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `edit_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `featuered` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_price` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `post_img` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uploads/no_image.jpg',
  `post_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_ref` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`,`post_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: we'll need more info than that.. Can you post your table structure and indexes?

Comment: You can't speed it up if you want to fetch *all* records at once.  Do you?  If not, what kind of data do you want to fetch?

Comment: Please check the table structure.

I am using it on classified website and it must fetch all records but by pagination php pagination using ....

but when i see olx and other site there and millions of record and these websites are fast ....

Comment: @MShahzadAkram - what indices have you set up on that table? What data are you retrieving? All of it? Subsets? Every column?

Comment: just post_id is primary key and no other indexes.

Comment: @MShahzadAkram - how are you querying for records? You need to figure out what criteria your SELECT statements are using, and add indices as appropriate.

Comment: You talked about "pagination"? Ever tried [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)?

Comment: I am using php pagination with all records and i am select some of fields from table..... like title , description and date , price .... not fetching all columns .... on which column i can add index ?

Comment: @MShahzadAkram - I can't answer that without seeing your SELECT statements. If you're selecting on `post_date`, then add an index on it. If you're selecting on `post_title`, add an index on it.

Comment: SELECT
  `post_id`,
  `post_title`,
  `post_des`,
  `post_date`,
  `post_status`,
  `user_id`,
  `post_price`,
FROM `post`

Comment: also please if need to add indexes , mentioned me if there is any alter query to add indexes on the existing table ?

Comment: for pagination you should be doing two queries one that gets the total count `select count(id) as post_count from post` and then using an limit clause in your query to get only the the records you need. @ZombieHunters comment links to the docs for how to use limit.

Comment: @MShahzadAkram - is that your real query? So you're querying your table with 1,000,000 rows and printing all of them out, in no particular order, every time?

Comment: @ZombieHunter yes you are right i am using this query and passing to a pagination class who will count and then set limit of 0,16 and return query and then i will use that further to fetch record to display .....

Comment: @andrewsi yes i am using this query ... but fetching required record from 10,000,00 total...

Comment: @MShahzad: try adding an `ORDER BY`, `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses to your statement: what difference do they make?

Comment: I just try this and nothing affect on query timing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to read this first :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

And this :
[How do MySQL indexes work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567981/how-do-mysql-indexes-work)

Comment: Basically i am not using any join to other tables .... i have primary key in this table and i don't think there is need to add more indexes.

please guide me if there is needed.

thanks

Comment: Indexes can still improve query performance even if there are no other joins. @MaximeD, please add more information to your answer; link-only answers are frowned upon.