# MYSQL (NOT IN) query is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

i don't know why this query take 45 min to give me the result

table1= 831293 row

table2= 2000.000 row

```
SELECT ID, name FROM table1 WHERE name not IN (SELECT name FROM table2 )  LIMIT 831293
```

my.cnf file look like this :

```
max_allowed_packet  = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
innodb_log_file_size    = 256M 
query_cache_type        = 1
query_cache_limit   = 1M
```

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: try running EXPLAIN on the query.. you probably dont have your indexes set up correctly... also look at NOT EXISTS as opposed to NOT IN because its usually faster

Comment: Please add the output of `EXPLAIN` <your query> and the table definitions.

Comment: i'm using innodb index @h2ooooooooo

Comment: what is purpose of limit clause?

Comment: i'm using where to get specific number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an index on name?

If you have to loop each time through table2 per row, you effectively loop through 831293*200000 rows, which is a lot.

When you have an index on name, you can get a major performance increase, as it is easier to search for a name in this index. (probably even O(1) as there will probably be a hashtable)

you can do this as follows

```
ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD INDEX (`name`)
```

Comment: Thomas Thank u dude your absolutly right, can u give me more explanation about how index on name make my query so much faster

Comment: I,d like to, but here is an explanation that will be far better then mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567981/how-do-mysql-indexes-work

Answer (score 1):

This select is very expensive because in the worst case for every record in table1 you must go through 2.000.000 records in table2. I am not MySQL specialist, but on the Oracle platform I would consider indexing and table spaces for table2.

BTW, the LIMIT part is useless.

Comment: i'm using limit to get a specific number of rows from table 1

Comment: I think, that in this case the LIMIT statement limits the whole result, not the table 1 rows. If you want to limit table 1, then use something like this SELECT ID, name FROM (select ID, name from table1 LIMIT 831293)  WHERE name not IN (SELECT name FROM table2 )

Answer (score 1):

agreed on:  (a) add the indexes and (b) the limit clause is useless.

consider a 'left outer join' - it will bring all rows from the "left" table even where no join value in the "right" table exists - then you filter out the non-desired "right" values.

something like:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.name 
FROM table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 
on t1.name = t2.name
where t2.name is null;
```

note:  sql above assumes name is unique in t2, and not unique in t1.

Answer (score 0):

I think using Exist will be faster.Try This

```
select Id,name from
(
    select table1.ID as ID, table1.name as name  
    FROM table1 inner join table2 
    on table1.name=table2.name
)
    WHERE not EXISTS
    (
    select 1  
    FROM table1 inner join table2 
    on table1.name=table2.name);
```

Comment: i get this message when i try to execute not exists 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE not EXISTS