# Best way to store working hours and query it efficiently

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design

I'm planning to store working hours for shops. I'm wondering what might be the best modeling for the working hours field so that I can get a list of open/closed shops at the current moment in very efficient way.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

To store normal operation hours, you would need to store a number of records containing:

- Shop - INTEGER
- DayOfWeek - INTEGER (0-6)
- OpenTime - TIME
- CloseTime - TIME

I assume for example that each shop has reduced hours during national holidays, or has plant shutdowns, so you would also need to store some override records:

- Shop - INTEGER
- OverrideStartDate - DATE
- OverrideEndDate - DATE
- DayOfWeek - INTEGER (0-6)
- AltOpenTime - TIME
- AltCloseTime - TIME
- Closed - INTEGER (0, 1)

To find open shops is trivial, but you also need to check if there are override hours:

```
SELECT Shop
FROM OverrideHours
WHERE OverrideStartDate <= NOW()
AND OverrideEndDate >= NOW()
AND DayOfWeek = WEEKDAY(NOW())
```

If there are any record returned, those shops have alternate hours or are closed.

There may be some nice SQL-fu you can do here, but this gives you the basics.

**EDIT**

I haven't tested this, but this should get you close:

```
SELECT Normal.Shop
FROM Normal
LEFT JOIN Override
ON Normal.Shop = Override.Shop
AND Normal.DayOfWeek = Override.DayOfWeek
AND NOW() BETWEEN Override.OverrideStartDate AND Override.OverrideEndDate
WHERE Normal.DayOfWeek = WEEKDAY(NOW())
AND ((Override.Shop IS NULL AND TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN Normal.OpenTime AND Normal.CloseTime)
 OR  (Override.Shop IS NOT NULL AND Override.Closed <> 1 AND TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN Override.AltOpenTime AND Override.AltCloseTime))
```

**EDIT**

As for efficiency, it is efficient in the sense that you only have to make one call to MySQL which is often a bottleneck if it is across a network.  You'll have to test and see whether this performs to your specifications.  If not, you may be to play with some indices.

**EDIT**

Testing.  Not complete testing, but some.

```
mysql> select * from Normal;
+------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| Shop | DayOfWeek | OpenTime | CloseTime |
+------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|    1 |         1 | 09:00:00 | 17:00:00  | 
|    1 |         5 | 09:00:00 | 16:00:00  | 
|    2 |         1 | 09:00:00 | 17:00:00  | 
|    2 |         5 | 09:00:00 | 17:00:00  | 
+------+-----------+----------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from Override;
+------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------+
| Shop | OverrideStartDate | OverrideEndDate | DayOfWeek | AltOpenTime | AltCloseTime | Closed |
+------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------+
|    2 | 2010-12-01        | 2010-12-31      |         1 | 09:00:00    | 18:00:00     |      0 | 
|    2 | 2010-12-01        | 2010-12-31      |         5 | 09:00:00    | 18:00:00     |      0 | 
|    1 | 2010-12-01        | 2010-12-31      |         1 | 09:00:00    | 17:00:00     |      1 | 
+------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @whenever = TIMESTAMP('2010-11-23 16:05');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT WEEKDAY(@whenever);
+--------------------+
| WEEKDAY(@whenever) |
+--------------------+
|                  1 | 
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT Normal.Shop FROM Normal LEFT JOIN Override ON Normal.Shop = Override.Shop AND Normal.DayOfWeek = Override.DayOfWeek AND @whenever BETWEEN Override.OverrideStartDate AND Override.OverrideEndDate WHERE Normal.DayOfWeek = WEEKDAY(@whenever) AND ((Override.Shop IS NULL AND TIME(@whenever) BETWEEN Normal.OpenTime AND Normal.CloseTime)  OR  (Override.Shop IS NOT NULL AND Override.Closed <> 1 AND TIME(@whenever) BETWEEN Override.AltOpenTime AND Override.AltCloseTime));
+------+
| Shop |
+------+
|    1 | 
|    2 | 
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @whenever = TIMESTAMP('2010-11-23 17:05');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT Normal.Shop FROM Normal LEFT JOIN Override ON Normal.Shop = Override.Shop AND Normal.DayOfWeek = Override.DayOfWeek AND @whenever BETWEEN Override.OverrideStartDate AND Override.OverrideEndDate WHERE Normal.DayOfWeek = WEEKDAY(@whenever) AND ((Override.Shop IS NULL AND TIME(@whenever) BETWEEN Normal.OpenTime AND Normal.CloseTime)  OR  (Override.Shop IS NOT NULL AND Override.Closed <> 1 AND TIME(@whenever) BETWEEN Override.AltOpenTime AND Override.AltCloseTime));
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SET @whenever = TIMESTAMP('2010-12-25 16:05');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT Normal.Shop FROM Normal LEFT JOIN Override ON Normal.Shop = Override.Shop AND Normal.DayOfWeek = Override.DayOfWeek AND @whenever BETWEEN Override.OverrideStartDate AND Override.OverrideEndDate WHERE Normal.DayOfWeek = WEEKDAY(@whenever) AND ((Override.Shop IS NULL AND TIME(@whenever) BETWEEN Normal.OpenTime AND Normal.CloseTime)  OR  (Override.Shop IS NOT NULL AND Override.Closed <> 1 AND TIME(@whenever) BETWEEN Override.AltOpenTime AND Override.AltCloseTime));
+------+
| Shop |
+------+
|    2 | 
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @whenever = TIMESTAMP('2010-11-23 17:05');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT WEEKDAY(@whenever);
+--------------------+
| WEEKDAY(@whenever) |
+--------------------+
|                  1 | 
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT Normal.Shop FROM Normal LEFT JOIN Override ON Normal.Shop = Override.Shop AND Normal.DayOfWeek = Override.DayOfWeek AND @whenever BETWEEN Override.OverrideStartDate AND Override.OverrideEndDate WHERE Normal.DayOfWeek = WEEKDAY(@whenever) AND ((Override.Shop IS NULL AND TIME(@whenever) BETWEEN Normal.OpenTime AND Normal.CloseTime)  OR  (Override.Shop IS NOT NULL AND Override.Closed <> 1 AND TIME(@whenever) BETWEEN Override.AltOpenTime AND Override.AltCloseTime));
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Great answer! Quick question: Would it be advisable to place indexes on `Shop`, `DayOfWeek`, `OpenTime` AND `CloseTime`?

Comment: @RabidFire, see the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049283/mysql-indexes-what-are-the-best-practises .  If the primary efficiency you're looking for is querying (as opposed to insertion, for example), then adding an index to any field used in a WHERE or JOIN ON should speed up the search.  You'll have to test to see which one's are the most effective.

Comment: @RobertGowland And what if night bussinsess opens at 5PM and closses  at 3AM the next day?

Comment: @Antoniossss, You could do multiple entries per day... day 1 17:00-11:59:59, day 2 00:00-3:00, day 2 17:00-11:59:59, day 3 00:00-3:00, etc... your code will just have to be such that it expects multiple time entries per day. Or, depending on your needs, you may have to develop a different model.

Comment: @RobertGowland Could you please tell what do you mean by `AltOpenTime` and `AltCloseTime`? [Someone need to know it](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44790658#44790658) :)

Comment: @Sami and @Belle , "each shop has reduced hours during national holidays, or has plant shutdowns" and that's purpose of the `Override` table. The "alt" in the column name does indeed stand for "alternative". As you can see from the query, if there is an entry in the `Override` table, the hours from that table are used instead.

Comment: Hello I'm stucked with a similar problem but in a more complex way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683381/how-to-design-mongodb-dataset-for-opening-hours-datamodel

Answer (score 9):

Let's consider all opening hours are the same every week. So what about following table:

- shop_id - INTEGER (or any unique identifier of the shop)
- week_day - INTEGER (0=Monday - 6=Sunday)
- opens_at - TIME (use your local timezone)
- closes_at - TIME (use your local timezone)

Make a table for shops identified by `shop_id` and then insert the opening hours, i.e:

- 1, 0, 8:00, 17:00
- ...
- 1, 5, 8:00, 12:00
- 2, 0, 7:30, 12:30
- 2, 0, 13:30, 17:30
- 2, 1, 7:30, 12:30
- 2, 1, 13:30, 17:30
- ...

and then SELECT:

```
SELECT shop_id
FROM opening_hours
WHERE WEEKDAY(NOW()) = week_day
AND TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN opens_at AND closes_at
```