# How to Avoid Complete Table Scan in Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I want to creating a website where users can sign up in website and upload 20 images to their account. (planning to allow users to upload unlimited images in future)

I have two tables in database.
One for keeping user data
Table name - members
Fields- userid, username, password, email.
Other for saving image path
Table name- images
Fields - userid, imagepath

So I can display images of a user in his page searching image path from table 'images'

Things are working fine. But if the number of users grow this will become slower.
For example - If there is 50000 users I should check all the rows to find images uploaded by a single user
ie;
50000 userid * 20 images/user = 1000000 scans for table rows
This will make the system slow and make overload.
What I should do to avoid this?

Comment: You will need to use indexes. How to design them varies depending on your database structure.

Comment: hm... I heard about database indexes, but don't know how to use it. Can u please give be a good tutorial link for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create index on userid field in second table. 
Syntax:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

[What are the biggest benefits of using INDEXES in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696897/what-are-the-biggest-benefits-of-using-indexes-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

create a Schema like this,

```
CREATE TABLE dataTable
(
    `userid` INT NOT NULL, 
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY (`userID`),
    CONSTRAINT tb1_uq UNIQUE (`username`)
);

CREATE TABLE pathTable
(
    `userid` INT NOT NULL, 
    `imagepath` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk FOREIGN KEY  (`userID`) REFERENCES dataTable(`userid`)
);
```

specify that `userid` of `pathTable` as a foreign key that references to the certain table's (*dataTable*) primary key and the server automatically indexed it which will make it faster searching.