# Why and where to use INDEXes - pros and cons

Tags: mysql, sql, select, indexing

I'm quite new to database programming and I am wondering what the negative effects of indexes are? As far as I understood, indexes speed up operations which have to search the database for a specific value (for example a SELECT).

Consider this example:

For the table `Example`, with an index on column `user_name`, the operation:

```
SELECT TestField FROM Example WHERE user_name=XXXX
```

Will be faster as a result of the Index.

My question is: what are cons of using indexes? If an index just give us pros (performance gaining), why aren't they set as default?

Comment: related question, possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696897/what-are-the-biggest-benefits-of-using-indexes-in-mysql

Comment: Indexes are not free. They have to be built and updated, so inserts and updates will be slower.

Comment: try asking this same question here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well you can probably fill books about indices but in short here a few things to think about, when creating an index:

While it (mostly) speeds up a select, it slows down inserts, updates and deletes because the database engine does not have to write the data only, but the index, too.
An index need space on hard disk (and much more important) in RAM. An index that can not be held in RAM is pretty useless.
An index on a column with only a few different values doesn't speed up selects, because it can not sort out much rows (for example a column "gender", which usually has only two different values - male, female).

If you use MySQL for example you can check, if the engine uses an index by adding "explain" before the select - for your above example `EXPLAIN SELECT TestField FROM Example WHERE username=XXXX`

Answer (score 16):

**What are indexes for, what are they in database?**

Without index on column `user_name` system would have to scan the entire `Example` table on a row-by-row basis to find all matching entries. If the data distribution in particular table points that there are only a few rows or so this is clearly an inefficient way of obtaining those rows.

However, when using indexes, you are redirecting the power of search to a different, tree structure, that has faster lookups and very small depth.

Please have in mind, that indexes are pure redundancy. Database index is just like a telephone book one or any other index in a book you might be willing to read (probably a part of, to quickly find what you're looking for).

If you are interested in a chapter of a book the index lets you find it relatively quickly so that you don't have to skim through many pages to get it.

**Why aren't indexes created on default?**

Index is a data structure that is created alongside a table and maintains itself whenever a table is changed. The fact of it's existance implies usage of data storage.

If you would index every column on a large table, the storage needed to keep indexes would exceed the size of table itself by far.

Self maintenance of an index structure also means that whenever an `UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE` occurs, the index has to be updated (it's done automatically and does not require your action), but that **costs time** which means these operations are performed slower.

There are situations, when you need to retrieve most of the table (eg 90% of rows will be in the output), or the entire table, and in this case Sequence scan of the whole table (behaviour without an index) would be more efficient than doing the tree traversal and leaf node chain (which is the behaviour for navigating the index tree structure).

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why don't we use an index as a default is the maintenance problem.
i.e when we generally update(insert,delete,or update) that particular column which is indexed in a table then the index must be updated dynamically which is a bit time consuming process. Moreover it becomes an overhead to  maintain this index.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a handful of cons for using Indexes where they are not required.
Adding indexes in table lead to slower performance on every Insert or Update operation. It leads to more storage and are also a maintenance overhead as Indexes become become fragmented or outdated and need to be organized.
They are also not very useful for smaller table.

In short, know your use case. Only create indexes on large tables and on columns with high cardinality and that are being frequently queried on

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

Depends on how you have your indexes but essentially they are unique identifiers for each table row usually incremented by one value for example:

```
mytable{
 index   |  name  |   m/f   | age 
     1   | bob    | male    |  22 |
     2   | joe  b | male    |  27 |
     3   | sam    | female  |  42 |
     4   | bef    | female  |  21 |
}
```

See how we can check the number 3 for "sam" instead of going through each table each row and each column..

Comment: Please clarify how this answers the question?

Comment: I gave a quick set of basic fundamentals, check Stefan P answer:)