# How to create index for existing table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Our server gets slow, "To get data from mysql database". So I search for it on google. They told me, "Use INDEX for the select query to get data from the database it becomes more fastest execution".

Comment: completely true. Thanks for the information.

Comment: enable slow_log, run explain on the queries and make sensable indexes for those queries or maybe a query rewite is even needed..  But keep in mind adding a index does not force MySQL into using it as the optimizer is costs based..  Don't just blindly add indexes as redundent indexes might confuse the optimizer into using a wrong index and worse performance..

Comment: maybe u can have a  look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29842947/11930311

Comment: I have executed this query "CREATE INDEX identifier_idx ON room_info(identifier);" in my local system, [ it's affected 0 rows ]. But does not create any INDEX on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Index** is a small copy of a database table sorted by key values.

U need to create index first.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name(column_name)
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
USE INDEX (index_name)
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Seams like SQL Server (MSSQL) code as `WITH (INDEX(index_name))` is not valid MySQL

Comment: @MannersW Thank you. Is it work for the existing table in MySQL?

Comment: @sharath3599201 the second query in his answer will not work in MySQL as that seams to be SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax

Comment: `USE INDEX (index_name)` forcing MySQL into using a index is generally a bad idea..

Comment: Sorry for that, I doesn't notice is MySQL, I had UPDATE my answer for MySQL. You can have a try on it.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland is it "CREATE INDEX" query works for the existing table in MYSQL?