# INDEXING IN mysql when using multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, datatables

In my project I am using DataTables plugin to display data in table from database.

Every column has filter so user can filter data based on input on each column.

I am confused how to setup indexes, do ever column need index?

Is it good practice to index every column in table?

My table have 6 columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842622/why-and-where-to-use-indexes-pros-and-cons

Comment: Sanity check: In your DataTable, are you using `serverSide: true`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why and where to use INDEXes - pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842622/why-and-where-to-use-indexes-pros-and-cons)