# Complex (or very, very simple) MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a database that handles dialogue translation for projects.

I have a **project** table, a **dialogue** table, and a **translation** table.

Each entry in each table has an *id* column.

- **dialogue** has a `projectID` column that indicates the project the dialogue is a part of.
- **translation** has a `dialogueID` column that indicates the dialogue entry being translated.

So to help explain this problem, here's a pseudo-query I've constructed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM translation 
WHERE (translation.dialogueID refers to dialogue where dialogue.projectID = X)
```

Basically, I want to fetch all translation entries for project X. Since there's no direct route from project -> translation, I'd have to go through project -> dialogue, then dialogue -> translation. I've opted to just add a `projectID` to the translation table in the meantime, but it is a little clunky.

Comment: Are you asking about using two JOINs?

Comment: No clue. I've never used the JOIN instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what the id is of the project (X) then you could use:

```
SELECT t.* FROM translation AS t, dialogue AS d 
WHERE t.dialogueID = d.id AND d.projectID = X
```

If you don't know the project id but you know it's name (X) or something that you can refer to it, you can use:

```
SELECT t.* FROM translation AS t, dialogue AS d, project AS p 
WHERE t.dialogueID = d.id AND d.projectID = p.id AND p.name='X'
```

Comment: I see. So it's actually iterating through every unique pairing of a translation and dialogue row in the first query? That's pretty crazy. I had no idea you could do something like this. Thanks a lot for the quick response. Works perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I would recommend indexing your id columns if you haven't already to speed up the select process if you're iterating heaps of rows.  There's a good discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696897/what-are-the-biggest-benefits-of-using-indexes-in-mysql

Comment: I would recommend using JOIN. It's been around for 20 years, so let's start using it!