# Derby: Full Text Search

Tags: search, text, derby

I have a gigantic data of more than 2500000000 records distributed among 10 tables in derby. There are two columns "floraNfauna" and "locations" common in each table. Now I have to find a particular "floraNfauna" found at particular "locations", so I use "select" query with "like" e.g. "select * from tables where floraNfauna like('%fish%') and locations like('%shallow water bodies%')"; and it takes days to finally fetch the results which count below 1000 sometimes. After searching I found that "full text search" would be the best and faster approach to this. Can you help me with an example?

Comment: What is the size of the RAM in your server / pc. Please also mention the details of the table. `desc`

Comment: The system has 4GB Ram with a dual core processor clocked at 2.1 GHz. The tables have only two columns each first is "floraNfauna" varchar(50) and second is "locations" varchar(100).

Comment: 2500000000 is huge.. You seriously need to consider about upgrading your RAM first and most importantly index your table...

Comment: How to index the table? On both columns separately or a single index for both the columns? I did try the second one to create a single index for both the columns but still it takes 2-3 days to go through the complete data.

Comment: See the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Derby integrates nicely with Lucene, which is a full-text search engine.

Read more about that here: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/LuceneIntegration

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you must consider indexing your table. Here is an SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696897/what-are-the-biggest-benefits-of-using-indexes-in-mysql) which definitely would help to know more about **Why to index a DB table**.
More about [Adding Indexes to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-to-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables).

Secondly, if you are using a centralized database, then definitely consider upgrading your server hardware configuration.

Thanks, hope it helps.