# joining mysql tables or making the queries run faster

Tags: php, mysql

I admit am not the brightest when it comes to joining database tables so would like some help. Currently I have 2 queries, the main one being:

```
SELECT 
    s.id AS show_id, 
    start_date, 
    end_date
FROM `show` s, `theater_type` tt
WHERE
    s.theater = tt.theater_id AND
    image = 1 AND
    start_date > '2015-05-21' AND
    genre_id IN (1,2,3,12,13,17,21) AND
    tt.type_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

This is filtering and returning shows I need. So far it is excellent but for each show I also need its average rating. As a lumberjack I am looping through the results from above and using this query to retrieve the average for each `show_id` with:

```
SELECT AVG(rating) AS avgr FROM pro_reviews WHERE show_id = X
```

This is fine too but often times the first query returns more than 1k of results so the whole process runs more than 10s which is unacceptable for the end user.

I'm looking to join the queries and get it all in one shot. Maybe this won't be faster either but I'm out of options.

This is what I tried, obviously it's wrong because it only returns one row:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(rating) AS avgr,
    allshows.show_id,
    allshows.start_date,
    allshows.end_date
FROM 
    pro_reviews pr,
    (
        SELECT s.id AS show_id, start_date, end_date
        FROM `show` s, theater_type tt
        WHERE s.theater = tt.theater_id AND image = 1 AND start_date > '2015-05-21' AND genre_id IN (1,2,3,12,13,17,21) AND tt.type_id IN (1,2,3,4)
    ) allshows
WHERE allshows.show_id = pr.show_id
```

Explain first select returns

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  tt  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    209     Using where
1   SIMPLE  s   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5678    Using where; Using join buffer
```

Comment: What does `explain select...` for your first query says ? Add that into the question. As a side note aggregate function without `group by` always returns one row.

Comment: Try GROUP BY pr.show_id

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty added explain result. As far as I know if I use group by it will not return rows if I don't have any ratings in the second table for a specific show and I need all even if the average is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    AVG(pr.rating) AS avgr
    s.id AS show_id, 
    start_date, 
    end_date
FROM `show` s 
JOIN `theater_type` tt
ON s.theater = tt.theater_id
LEFT JOIN `pro_reviews` pr
ON s.id = pr.show_id
WHERE
    image = 1 AND
    start_date > '2015-05-21' AND
    genre_id IN (1,2,3,12,13,17,21) AND
    tt.type_id IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY s.id
```

Comment: Thanks for that but as I said in the comments using `GROUP BY` will eliminate all shows which don't have ratings in the second table

Comment: @slash197 Ok I understand you comment. For this purpose you just need left join in `pro_reviews` table and you need group by of `s.id` not `pr.show_id`

Comment: And you must add indexes based on `Explain`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Unfortunately it doesn't help me, this way it's ten times slower than using separate queries.

Comment: If you add indexes properly its must not  slower then separate query . But at first you need to learn how to use index . This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049283/mysql-indexes-what-are-the-best-practices) may help you

Comment: I have indexes for both tables set to primary and unique

Comment: @slash197 In short , you  have to use FULLTEXT [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) too. From this [Anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621884/database-development-mistakes-made-by-application-developers) You may get idea to how to use appropriate indices. Please read more about index . Index is not only primary and unique

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view

   CREATE VIEW all_shows AS
   SELECT s.id AS show_id, start_date, end_date

   FROM `show` s, theater_type tt

   WHERE s.theater = tt.theater_id AND image = 1 AND 
   genre_id IN (1,2,3,12,13,17,21) AND tt.type_id IN (1,2,3,4);
2. Then do Your select using this view

   SELECT 
       AVG(pro_reviews.rating) AS avgr,
       all_shows.show_id,
       all_shows.start_date,
       all_shows.end_date

   FROM pro_reviews

   INNER JOIN 
       all_shows ON (all_shows.show_id = pr.show_id)

   WHERE all_shows.start_date > '2015-05-21'

   GROUP BY pro_reviews.show_id;