# SQL Returning error even though query successful

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a basic web form that takes 3 inputs and inserts them into a database table. The DB set up:

```
    require_once 'MDB2.php';
    include "sql-connect.php";

    $host = 'host.yyy.uk';
    $dbName = 'user01';
    $dsn = "mysql://$username:$password@$host/$dbName"; 

    $db = &MDB2::connect($dsn); 
    if (PEAR::isError($db)) { 
        die($db->getMessage());
    }

    $db->setFetchMode(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
```

But even if the data is entered correctly into the DB and the data is inputted into the DB, php returns an error (Invalid query: Duplicate entry 'AAA123(ACode)' for key 'PRIMARY). This is my code for handling the form:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MODULES (APart, ACode, ATitle) VALUES ('$_POST[APart]', '$_POST[ACode]', '$_POST[ATitle]')";

    mysql_query($sql);

    $endResult = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$endResult) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $sql;
        die($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, 'Invalid query: Duplicate entry 'AAA123' for key 'PRIMARY'  this is where 'AAA123' is the entry for ACode

Comment: Maybe the error is it's way of saying you should stop using `mysql_` and use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead...

Comment: as the error say, you cant have Duplicate entry for the primary key...

Comment: @amirbar that's the thing, the entries don't exist in the DB

Comment: @Rasclatt I'm very new to this, and have no control over how the Database is set up, bar being able to modify the tables, can I still use mysqli?

Comment: Yeah you can use either mysqli or pdo. They are libraries though php

Comment: @Rasclatt Great I'll give that a go

Comment: Personally I would go with pdo, but you'll probably find mysqli_ more familiar

Comment: This query is wide open to SQL injection. `$_POST[APart]` should not be concatenated directly into the SQL query, this is an unsafe practice.

Comment: @Ian yea I didn't include the part where i assigned them as variables, but will make sure I do when this code goes live.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the query twice.

The first time, it succeeds but you do nothing with the result.

The second time, it fails - however, first succeeds, so you get some partial success (data is created).

Just remove the duplicate.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MODULES (APart, ACode, ATitle) VALUES ('$_POST[APart]', '$_POST[ACode]', '$_POST[ATitle]')";

    // mysql_query($sql); /* REMOVE THIS LINE - this query succeeds */

    $endResult = mysql_query($sql); /* LEAVE THIS LINE - this fails if the first succeeds, because of your key constraints */

    if (!$endResult) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $sql;
        die($message);
    }
}
```

And also, look into PDO and MySQL libraries to prevent yourself from injection.

Answer (score 0):

*Error:Duplicate entry* means you are trying to insert a row which is already present in your Database.

**Solution** 
Remove the primary key from the column (Acode) or add unique index on multiple columns instead of the primary key.

[Indexes Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049283/mysql-indexes-what-are-the-best-practices)