# Is the following SQL good or bad practice from a performance perspective?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I was hoping if any of you could be of any help, if I have a huge database with million of entries and all I need is information relating to a specific year (say, 2015), if I use the following query, performance wise will this be best practice or is there another way to have a better query,

```
CREATE INDEX table1_idx ON table1 (date_column);
SELECT text, date_column
FROM table1
WHERE datepart(yyyy, date_column) = 2015;
```

Any help relating to this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049283/mysql-indexes-what-are-the-best-practices. This may answer your question

Answer (score 0):

If this is about SQL Server, that is not the way to do it. Using any functions on the fields makes in non-SARGable.

Always use correct search criteria like this:

```
SELECT text, date_column
FROM table1
WHERE date_column >= '20150101' and date_column < '20160101'
```

You might also want to consider adding `text` as included column to prevent key lookups:

```
CREATE INDEX table1_idx ON table1 (date_column) include (text)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can't use an index range scan operation, due to the function wrapped around the column. The function has to be evaluated for *every* row in the table.

To get an index range scan operation, do comparisons on the *bare* column.

For example:

```
 SELECT t.text
      , t.date_column
   FROM table1 t
  WHERE t.date_column >= '2015-01-01'
    AND t.date_column  < '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```